A novel (and a movie) about a village in southern France where a strange succession of events happens
I read this book many decades ago, in French original. A few years later, I saw the movie (most probably with the same title) that was made about it, also in French. I'm positive the author is French and originates from Southern France.
The action is in a small village in southern France, many decades ago, I'd guess early 20th century. Most probably in Provence but there are places in Languedoc that might fit.
It begins when an old man, in what will eventually be his deathbed, starts to mumble meaningless words.  I remember  perfectly the verb used to describe that : "déparler" which is totally obsolete now. But the meaning is easy to guess. "Parler" means "to speak", so "déparler" is to speak in an incorrect way, a bad way, possibly to curse.
And indeed the other villagers suspect that his mumbling might be curses, because a succession of disasters hit the village: drought, fires, death of animals....
One might consider it is "out of topic" because, independently, none of the events is abnormal per se. Only the succession is strange.
The entire atmosphere of the book, however, follows the superstition of the villagers who are convinced that the old man brought them this curse, but they fear to kill him. And indeed, when he finally dies a natural way, everything returns to normalcy.
More details : formally the head of the village is a man, but in fact most of the important decisions are made by a middle-aged woman with an extremely strong personality. Possibly a widow, or perhaps never married, but certainly without a husband at the time of the events.
There is also the "idiot du village", unable to do a real job. I'm not sure he can help at all, but at that time no village would let his "idiot" starve. At some point of book (and the movie), one realises that the "strong" woman has regular sexual intercourse with him. IIRC, he dies in a fire that destroys a building (abarn ?), and she cries with a sincere sorrow.

In roughly which year/decade did you read/watch this?

@LogicDictates Watched the movie (on TV) about 20 or so years ago, read the novel maybe only a few years before, because I still remembered clearly reading it when watching the movie. But the novel is probably much older, though, I believe, still decades after the events it describes. Or possibly, also early 20th century.

Sounds a bit like Tardi's Comic "Silence" (Obviously not the answer your are looking for ...) https://www.babelio.com/livres/Comes-Silence/1476826

I bet this is Colline (Hill) by Jean Giono (1929).
The story is set in Provence (southern France), next to the mountain of Lure, in a very small village called "Bastides Blanches". Giono was born in Manosque (Provence) and spent most of his life there, about 40km from the mountain of Lure.
As for the story, an old man warns others against nature taking revenge against humans. Characters start to freak out about it, and discuss a black cat appearing before disasters occur (earthquakes, lighting striking people, etc.). Then, several bad events indeed happen: water shortage in the village, a small girl getting sick, a fire spreading to the village…
In addition, the story features a "village idiot" called Gagou, who is the lover of Ulalie. Ulalie is depicted as a ugly, but strong, independent woman.
As you mention the word "déparler" (translated as "raving" in the 2016 translation in English by Paul Eprile), the novel includes a few occurrences of it, in particular one character uses it to describe the old man who is dying.
Finally, there was a TV movie adaptation of the novel in 1980.

The novel has en entry in en.WP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colline ; the English translation went in the wake of a prize awarded to Giono, Prix Brentano. The author has en entry as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Giono

@FrançoisJurain Indeed. My answer does include a link to the English version of the Wikipedia article, though it is quite terse. Perhaps there are better sources presenting the novel, for those who don't speak French and would be interested in learning more about the novel, but unfortunately I can't suggest anything in particular.

fr.WP + Glurgle Translate? The plot synopsis adds little to your answer. They adde a few words about the breakthrough writing and  réalisme merveilleux. https://fr-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Colline_(roman)?_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp
